# Why is my custom exception unpickle failing

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
import pickle

class ABError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super(ABError, self).__init__(a)
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

class ABCDError(ABError):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        super(ABCDError, self).__init__(a, b)
        self.c = c
        self.d = d

err = ABCDError("aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc", "ddddd")

pickled_err = pickle.dumps(err)

original_err = pickle.loads(pickled_err)  # Fails
```

I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pickle_pain.py", line 19, in <module>
    original_err = pickle.loads(pickled_err)  # Fails
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1388, in loads
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1139, in load_reduce
    value = func(*args)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 5 arguments (2 given)
```

I've done some googling, but struggling to find a good answer for why this happens, and not desperate to start learning the pickle serialisation format in order to step through this :-/

Edit: The behaviour is the same in python3, though the error message is slightly nicer:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pickle_pain.py", line 19, in <module>
    original_err = pickle.loads(pickled_err)  # Fails
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'b', 'c', and 'd'
```

Comment: Looks to me this is because the `Exception` class overrides `__setstate__`?

Comment: Just a note to try and point you in a useful direction: apparently when unpickling, the system tries to call __init__ with only 2 arguments. In Java environments, often it is mandated to have a default constructor that will be called via reflection and all other fields set via property setter methods. Either you need to take that approach: change your __init__ to work without the additional arguments and let the unpickling set them after __init__ has finished, or perhaps you can find a way with pickle to tell it the additional parameters it needs to supply to __init__ when unpickling.

Comment: You can further simplify your minimal example, because pickling and unpickling an `ABError` causes the same error.

Comment: Thanks - I've posed a more minimal version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808912/cannot-unpickle-exception-subclass

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot unpickle Exception subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808912/cannot-unpickle-exception-subclass)

Comment: Anyone reading this in the future, please vote to close as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808912/cannot-unpickle-exception-subclass

Answer (score 0):

I was answering a different question that linked to this one and they are kind of the same. **reduce** will return how to recreate the object and it bases it off of whats in self.args. Since you aren't passing all the args to Exception it breaks. If you need to be able to access the custom fields without doing e.args[0] for a and e.args[1] for b etc, just make properties.
Notice the Extended class still calls the Exception **init** not ABError.**init**.

```
import pickle

class ABError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super(ABError, self).__init__(a, b)
        
    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.args[0]

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.args[1]


class ABCDError(ABError):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        super(ABError, self).__init__(a, b, c, d)

    @property
    def c(self):
        return self.args[2]

    @property
    def d(self):
        return self.args[3]



err = ABCDError("aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc", "ddddd")

pickled_err = pickle.dumps(err)

original_err = pickle.loads(pickled_err)  # Fails
```