# Cannot unpickle Exception subclass

Tags: python

Simplified version of [Why is my custom exception unpickle failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41770024/why-is-my-custom-exception-unpickle-failing).

I am trying to pickle a 'simple' exception subclass. It pickles OK, but when unpickling it falls over:

```
import pickle

class ABError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

ab_err = ABError("aaaa", "bbbb")

pickled = pickle.dumps(ab_err)
original = pickle.loads(pickled)  # Fails
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p.py", line 12, in <module>
    original = pickle.loads(pickled)  # Fails
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1388, in loads
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1139, in load_reduce
    value = func(*args)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

An earlier comment suggested the issue is because the built in `Exception` class supplies a `__setstate_()` method. However, it's not clear to me if this is expected behaviour or not - it certainly seems surprising since doing the same thing with a subclass of `object` works OK.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `BaseException` class defines a custom [`__reduce__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__) method in [exceptions.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/exceptions.c#L129), which returns the list of arguments to pass to `__init__`. Exact code is

```
if (self->args && self->dict)
    return PyTuple_Pack(3, Py_TYPE(self), self->args, self->dict);
else
    return PyTuple_Pack(2, Py_TYPE(self), self->args);
```

According to `__reduce__` documentation,

- the first item of the tuple is the callable to invoke. Here, that will be the exception class.
- the second item is the tuple of arguments to pass to the callable. Here, that will be `self.args`.
- the third item is a dict to merge into `self.__dict__`.

So from this, `BaseException.__reduce__` will make unpickle invoke the exception's constructor with given args.

You have two options: either override `__reduce__`, or put the required arguments in self.args, either directly or by letting the parent class do it:

```
import pickle

class ABError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        # self.args = (a, b)
        # maybe better, let base class's __init__ do it =>
        super(ABError, self).__init__(a, b)

ab_err = ABError("aaaa", "bbbb")

pickled = pickle.dumps(ab_err)
original = pickle.loads(pickled)  # no longer fails
```

Note that the original issue comes from the rather naive way `BaseException` pickle handling works. It is fixed in the latest python3 releases. Your question's original code works fine on python 3.5 for instance.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. I had tried this (without success) on 3.4 but not on 3.5.

Comment: @TomDalton> Glad it helped. Btw I just edited, after seing `BaseException.__init__` sets `self.args`, so it's arguably cleaner invoking it that assigning manually.

Comment: Yep. Unfortunately the next issue I have is even when I can pickle ABError,  I have subclasses of it like `ABCError`, that still wont work. I can work around this until we move to 3.5 - I feel a lot better about this knowing it was seen as a problem by other people :)

Comment: This issue is present in 3.6.7

Comment: Can confirm that this issue is still present in 3.9.1

Comment: As far as I can tell, this problem was fixed in Python 3.5. I'm not sure what errors @cdosborn and@Marco are seeing.