# Why can't instances of this subclass of set be unpickled?

Tags: python, python-2.7, set, pickle

When I dump a class instance to a file with pickle module, it's successful, however, when I load the instance from the file, it failed with `TypeError` exception raised.

I found all subclass that derived from set will raise a `TypeError` when attempting to unpickle it.

```
class TreeKeys(set):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TreeKeys, self).__init__()

    def add(self, tk):
        assert tk.__class__ == tuple
        super(TreeKeys, self).add(tk)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = TreeKeys()
    a.add((1,2,3))
    with open('tmp.pickle', 'wb') as tmp_fd:
        pickle.dump(a, tmp_fd)
    with open('tmp.pickle', 'rb') as tmp_fd:
        obj = pickle.load(tmp_fd)  # this is the code line raise the TypeError exception.
    pass
```

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 182.3684.100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1664, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1658, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1068, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "G:/pycharm-projects/new_keyinfo/verify_treekeys.py", line 56, in <module>
    obj = pickle.load(tmp_fd)
  File "C:\Python27_64bit\Lib\pickle.py", line 1384, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python27_64bit\Lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Python27_64bit\Lib\pickle.py", line 1139, in load_reduce
    value = func(*args)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you didn't define your class' `__init__()` method to take an (optional) iterable argument like its base class, the built-in [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) class does, and `pickle` tries to call it with one to restore the instance's contents when it loads the file.

Here's a simple way to fix that:

```
import pickle

class TreeKeys(set):
    def __init__(self, iterable=None):
        if iterable is None:
            super(TreeKeys, self).__init__()
        else:
            super(TreeKeys, self).__init__(iterable)

    def add(self, tk):
        assert tk.__class__ == tuple
        super(TreeKeys, self).add(tk)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = TreeKeys()
    a.add((1,2,3))
    with open('tmp.pickle', 'wb') as tmp_fd:
        pickle.dump(a, tmp_fd)
    with open('tmp.pickle', 'rb') as tmp_fd:
        obj = pickle.load(tmp_fd)  # This will now work.
    print(obj)  # -> TreeKeys([(1, 2, 3)])
```

Comment: It's truly work now, however, with the original code that I provided, I substitute the set to list, It works. The list and set's __init() method both have an optional iterable argument, why list's subclass work, but set's subclass don't work? Do you know the root cause of this problem, or, can you detail this problem's root cause? Thank you.

Comment: It maybe a same problem with [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808912/cannot-unpickle-exception-subclass)