# Django Celery getting pickling error on throwing custom exception

Tags: python, django, celery, pickle

I'm using celery in a django application. In case of a failure I raise a custom exception, which is defined with this class:

```
class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, err_input, err_info=''):
        self.err_key, self.err_msg, self.app_domain = err_input
        self.message = self.err_msg
        super(CustomException, self).__init__(self.message)
        self.err_info = err_info

    def __str__(self):
        return '[{}] {}'.format(str(self.err_key), str(self.err_msg))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.message
```

the `error_info` is used for an internal logging purpose.
If I throw the message I get in the related celery task:

```
{
  "task_id": "0dfd5ef3-0df1-11eb-b74a-0242ac110002",
  "status": "FAILURE",
  "result": {
    "exc_type": "MaybeEncodingError",
    "exc_message": [
      "'PicklingError(\"Can\\'t pickle &lt;class \\'module.CustomException\\'&gt;: it\\'s not the same object as module.CustomException\")'",
      "\"(1, &lt;ExceptionInfo: CustomException('Error message')&gt;, None)\""
    ],
    "exc_module": "billiard.pool"
  },
  "traceback": null,
  "children": []
}
```

what am I misconfiguring in my exception class?

Comment: Any solution/s for it so far?

Comment: Yes the solution was to remove the call to `super(CustomException, self).__init__(self.message)`. As far as I remember from what I read Pickling is expecting an init function with only 1 parameter. So to avoid the error I either had to change the init of my `CustomException` to accept only 1 parameter or remove the call to super

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to remove the call to `super(CustomException, self).__init__(self.message)`.

From what I read Pickling is expecting an init function with only 1 parameter. So to avoid the error I either had to change the init of my `CustomException` to accept only 1 parameter or remove the call to super

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to use the approach explained in this answer:
[Cannot unpickle Exception subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808912/cannot-unpickle-exception-subclass)
as it allows you to handle cases where passing args to Parent class might actually be beneficial.
For this particular case it can be done as such:

```
class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, err_input, err_info=''):
        self.err_input = err_input
        self.err_info = err_info
        # place rest of code here
        super(CustomException, self).__init__(err_input, err_info)
    
    def __reduce__(self):
        return (CustomException, (self.err_input, self.err_info))
```