# Pickle fails when unpickling subclass of Exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I'm trying to pickle / unpickle a subclass of `Exception` via Python 3.9.1 `pickle` module. The `pickle.dumps` part works fine, but when I try to `pickle.loads` the result, I get an exception.

Here is an example:

File `my_exception.py`:

```py
class MyException (Exception):
    def __init__ (self) -> None:
        super().__init__("foo")
```

Command line:

```py
>>> import pickle
>>> import my_exception
>>> exc_bytes = pickle.dumps(my_exception.MyException())
>>> print(exc_bytes)
b'\x80\x04\x95*\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x0cmy_exception\x94\x8c\x0bMyException\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x03foo\x94\x85\x94R\x94.'
>>> pickle.loads(exc_bytes)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

It looks like `pickle` is not able to detect `MyException.__init__`'s args because somehow the `Exception.__init__`'s args are shadowing them. If I change `MyException.__init__`  as below, it works.

File `my_exception.py`:

```py
class MyException (Exception):
    def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__("foo")
```

Command line:

```py
>>> import pickle
>>> import my_exception
>>> exc_bytes = pickle.dumps(my_exception.MyException())
>>> print(exc_bytes)
b'\x80\x04\x95*\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x0cmy_exception\x94\x8c\x0bMyException\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x03foo\x94\x85\x94R\x94.'
>>> pickle.loads(exc_bytes)
MyException('foo')
```

The thing is that I have lots of `Exception`'s subclasses, and I'm writing those classes to be easily expanded by other people, without them having to worry about this problem. Therefore, it is not viable to add `*args, **kwargs` to all subclasses `__init__`s.

Is this a bug from Python or a bug in my code? Is there any other solution for this problem, besides the `*args, **kwargs`?

Comment: This may lead you the way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41770024/why-is-my-custom-exception-unpickle-failing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808912/cannot-unpickle-exception-subclass